# Show calendar on focus on date input

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a button alongside lightning:input with type="date".
When I click on the button I want to focus on the input and show calendar to pick a date but it focuses only and calendar is visible only after I click on the input. How to fire showing of the calendar after button click?

```
MARKUP:
<lightning:button onclick="{!c.setFocus}"/>
<lightning:input type="date" aura:id="dateInput"/>

CONTROLLER:
setFocus : function(component) {
    component.find('dateInput').focus();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this looks like it might not be possible. Reading the comments on this closed issue, it isn't something that will be supported: https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/issues/1519

Comment: @CallumMacErlich I guess  it should be possible because when we click by mouse it fires some event, so I guess there is some event we can fire programmatically